# Detect duplicates and create summarised rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a regular incoming CSV that looks like this (simplified):

```
Published   Station         TypeFuel    Price
1/09/2015   BP Seaford      ULP         129.9
1/09/2015   BP Seaford      Diesel      133.9
1/09/2015   BP Seaford      Gas         156.9
1/09/2015   Shell Newhaven  ULP         139.9
1/09/2015   Shell Newhaven  Diesel      150.9
1/09/2015   7-Eleven Malaga ULP         135.9
1/09/2015   7-Eleven Malaga Diesel      155.9
2/10/2015   BP Seaford      ULP         138.9
2/10/2015   BP Seaford      Diesel      133.6
2/10/2015   BP Seaford      Gas         157.9
```

*…Many more rows hidden.  Looking at around 200 stations, reporting every day 20-30 days.*

I need to summarise it down to look like this:

```
Published   Station         ULP     Diesel  Gas
1/09/2015   BP Seaford      129.9   133.9   156.9
1/09/2015   Shell Newhaven  139.9   150.9   
1/09/2015   7-Eleven Malaga 135.9   155.9   
2/09/2015   BP Seaford      138.9   133.6   157.9
```

Just taking baby steps with the Pandas tutorials and also fairly new to Python, but I believe these two should help me accomplish this task.

I believe I need to iterate through the CSV, and when Published and Station match, create a new row, transposing the ULP/Diesel/Gas prices into new columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`DataFrame.pivot_table()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) , pivotting based on the columns - `'Published','Station'` , taking values from column - `TypeFuel` for the new columns in the pivot table and using values from `Price` as its values. Example -

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   Published          Station TypeFuel  Price
0  1/09/2015       BP Seaford      ULP  129.9
1  1/09/2015       BP Seaford   Diesel  133.9
2  1/09/2015       BP Seaford      Gas  156.9
3  1/09/2015   Shell Newhaven      ULP  139.9
4  1/09/2015   Shell Newhaven   Diesel  150.9
5  1/09/2015  7-Eleven Malaga      ULP  135.9
6  1/09/2015  7-Eleven Malaga   Diesel  155.9
7  2/10/2015       BP Seaford      ULP  138.9
8  2/10/2015       BP Seaford   Diesel  133.6
9  2/10/2015       BP Seaford      Gas  157.9

In [7]: df.pivot_table(index=['Published','Station'],columns=['TypeFuel'],values='Price')
Out[7]:
TypeFuel                   Diesel    Gas    ULP
Published Station
1/09/2015 7-Eleven Malaga   155.9    NaN  135.9
          BP Seaford        133.9  156.9  129.9
          Shell Newhaven    150.9    NaN  139.9
2/10/2015 BP Seaford        133.6  157.9  138.9
```

---

If you don't want `Published` and `Station` to be indexes, you can call `.reset_index()` on the result of `pivot_table()` to reset the indexes. Example -

```
In [8]: df.pivot_table(index=['Published','Station'],columns=['TypeFuel'],values='Price').reset_index()
Out[8]:
TypeFuel  Published          Station  Diesel    Gas    ULP
0         1/09/2015  7-Eleven Malaga   155.9    NaN  135.9
1         1/09/2015       BP Seaford   133.9  156.9  129.9
2         1/09/2015   Shell Newhaven   150.9    NaN  139.9
3         2/10/2015       BP Seaford   133.6  157.9  138.9
```

Comment: If I had some additional fields (address, postcode, etc) that I want to have after/before the fuel prices as columns, can you point me to where they should go in your statements (which are working perfectly, thanks!) I assume they should all be the same, so in the index makes sense, but weary if there was some missing data

Comment: I think in `index` since anyway if you want those values in the resulting table, you would need to include them in the columns based on which grouping would take place.